# Объединение двух коллекций IQueryable

Tags: c#, mvc, linq

Имеется две коллекции IQueryable с разным источником данных, нужно объединить две коллекции для последующей передачи в представление.

`IQueryable<Post> list_news = null;
IQueryable<User> list_users = null;
list_news = db.Posts.Where(u => news_following_id.Contains(u.UserId));
list_users = db.Users.Where(u => news_following_id.Contains(u.UserId));`

Comment: `Enumerable.Join()`? [Документация с примером](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1) Вы же хотите в результате список постов по юзерам иметь?

Comment: У вас entity framework? Что мешает использовать навигационные свойства?

Comment: Результат должен быть пост, с информацией о пользователе который его отправил(ник) и информацией поста(фото и описание). Обе коллекции объединяет один UserId(название идентично в двух таблицах) и строка `news_following_id.Contains(u.UserId)` находит именно нужные мне данные, осталось их только правильно объеденить
Сейчас попробую ваш способ

Comment: @tym32167 как то пропустил это) Сейчас читаю и понимаю, что это то, что мне нужно, спасибо, сейчас буду делать)